# Git - pulling from master remote shows unstaged/changed files - how to determine source

Tags: git, git-remote, merge-conflict-resolution

This post involves several questions, as I'm not sure what's going on and need to as well know how to determine source of problem.

The repo is stored at Git Hub and I have access to it.  When I do an initial git clone everything works fine and I see all the files.  This is a Laravel project but that's not the main question however might be relevant.

I am doing this in a bash kernel for Windows, perhaps that is relevant.

when I open source tree (or type git status), I show about 20 files that are "changed" but unstaged.  There should be no changed or unstaged files in master.  Also, apparently one folder `/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/interactions/[files listed]` has a lowercase `i` for interactions, and there is both a `Interactions` and an `interactions` folder in the `lib` folder.  Perhaps at some point some files were wrongly named or the folder case was changed and windows or mac didn't like it.

My questions are:
1. How do I determine if there are actually changed/unstaged files on a remote branch?
2. If not, what in my system would be causing this, especially anything relating to case sensitivity?

Comment: There's no such thing as "changed/unstaged files on a remote branch".  Unstaged means the change is in a work tree but not in the index or database; the remote only cares about the database.  So after the checkout git thinks you have files out of sync with the remote.  What do you see if you do a `git diff`?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with case sensitivity on a Windows platform, though I don't know the specifics of why, or when the discrepancy happened.

This problem went away when I called `git clone ...` from inside my virtual machine (a Vagrant box) versus calling git clone from Windows on the shared folder.  There were then NO unstaged/changed files that hadn't been committed.

Moral of the story appears to be, run git in the environment you're working on the file system on through ssh, not in the shared folder in Windows.